# db connection from asp

Tags: sql, vbscript, odbc

I am trying to query a SQL database from an ASP file (using vbscript) but I get the following error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e4d'
[Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Cannot open database "XX" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

This is the code I use for the connection:

```
connString= "Driver=SQL Server Native Client
11.0;Server=XX\XX;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Database=XX"
sql = "SELECT * FROM Tanks"
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set recordSet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds like an authentication issue. You're using `Trusted_Connection=Yes`, so it's presumably using the local Windows accounts to authenticate to the database server. Does the logged-in account have access to server\database `XX\XX`? You could, alternatively, provide the user and password in the connection string (but `Trusted_Connection` would need to be omitted or set to `No` as the user/password arguments are ignore when `Trusted_Connection` is enabled).

Comment: The sql server is hosted in the same machine than the script and the logged-in account is the administrator account. How can I check if it has access to the database?